# Fullcalendar v5 problems with IE11

Tags: fullcalendar, internet-explorer-11, fullcalendar-5

It happened something strange to me. On my  work computer doesn't work fullcalendar v5 on internet explorer e11 but in my personal computer it works and it has a low version than my  work computer. any idea about this?

For example I can't see any example from the web page https://fullcalendar.io/

Or this code

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
    initialDate: '2020-06-07',
    allDaySlot:false,
    locale:'es',
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
    },
    events: [
      {
        title: 'All Day Event',
        start: '2020-06-01'
      },
      {
        title: 'Long Event',
        start: '2020-06-07',
        end: '2020-06-10'
      },
      {
        groupId: '999',
        title: 'Repeating Event',
        start: '2020-06-09T16:00:00'
      },
      {
        groupId: '999',
        title: 'Repeating Event',
        start: '2020-06-16T16:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Conference',
        start: '2020-06-11',
        end: '2020-06-13'
      },
      {
        title: 'Meeting',
        start: '2020-06-12T10:30:00',
        end: '2020-06-12T12:30:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Lunch',
        start: '2020-06-12T12:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Meeting',
        start: '2020-06-12T14:30:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Birthday Party',
        start: '2020-06-13T07:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Click for Google',
        url: 'http://google.com/',
        start: '2020-06-28'
      }
    ],
          slotLabelFormat: {
                hour: '2-digit',
                minute: '2-digit',
                omitZeroMinute: false,
                meridiem: false
            },
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

Comment: As per https://fullcalendar.io/getting-help it should be compatible with IE11 in theory. Perhaps your IE is set to run in compatibility mode by default (i.e. so it renders pages as if it was an older version of IE?). This is quite commonly done in company intranets to allow ongoing support for ancient intranet applications. If that's the case, you may need to add something to make your fullCalendar site an exception. But without seeing any code, or any error messages or other detailed information about the problem we can only guess or speculate.

Comment: I've tested [fullcalendar demos](https://fullcalendar.io/#demos) in IE 11 and it can work well. I'm in favor of ADyson's comment, fullcalendar can't work in IE 11 compatibility mode. You could check your work computer's IE settings to see if it uses compatibility mode. Besides, you should provide [a minimal, reproducibe code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can have a test and see how to help.

Comment: I dindn't put code because i can't see the web page of fullcalendar while in other computers I can see it.  The error that appears in console are only two points ":" and anyelse.

Comment: Have you checked the compatibility mode? Which version of IE 11 are you using? The  fullcalendar example can work well in my IE 11: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeQRX.png. You could compare the settings between the IE browsers and try to [reset the IE settings](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17441/windows-internet-explorer-change-reset-settings) in your work computer.

Comment: "The error that appears in console"...can you tell us the **exact** error messages in the console? And did you check compatibility mode yet?

Answer (score 1):

Have the same problem. IE console indicates that it doesn't understand `()=>{}` combination. And so to make it compatible all `=>` should be replaced with `function`